# How to reformat a Javascript Try/Catch to a then/catch

Tags: javascript

The following code is anAPI endpoint taking a URL of an image as input, and outputing the URL of the newly created thumbnail.

I am trying the refactor the try/catch, to a .then().catch(), as I intend to had more then()s, to upload the newly created thumbnail to AWS s3 for instance).

```
const express = require("express");
const jimp = require('jimp');
const { v1: uuidv1 } = require('uuid');
const router = express.Router();

// GET all data from watchlist
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  const url = req.body.url;
  const tempPath = './public/uploads/';
  const tempFileName = uuidv1();
  const tempURL = tempPath + tempFileName;
  const cleanedUrl = tempURL.slice(2, tempURL.length);

  try {
    jimp.read(url, (err, img) => {
      img.resize(120, 120)
        .quality(60)
        .write(tempURL)
    })
    res.status(201).json({ thumbUrl: `http://localhost:5000/${cleanedUrl}` });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({
      error: `${err})`,
    });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

The code I had in mind to remplace the Try/Catch, seems not to be working, as when using it, the API freezes and deliver no response (and no errors!?).

```
jimp.read(url, (err, img) => {
    img.resize(120, 120)
      .quality(60)
      .write(tempURL)
  })
    .then(() => {
      res.status(400).json({
        thumbUrl: `http://localhost:5000/${cleanedUrl}`,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(400).json({ error: `${err}` })
    })
```

If someone could point me the error (or some good ressources for dummy about how to use then/catch, I can't find any I understand online) I will be highly grateful!

Comment: Oh, you can't have async inside route handlers - this is what I have heard in my experience.

Comment: The first code looks very suspicious - it uses a callback, but `try`/`catch` won't catch callbacks called asynchronously

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman You *can* if you properly `catch` everywhere I believe, but it's a bad idea because it's easy to accidentally forget to catch and result in the process exiting

Comment: @CertainPerformance you're right, the first code is definitely not going to catch anything. Moreover, it would return a response before the `read` is completed. [The library appears to have a callback and a promise API](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp#installation), so what should happen is to drop the callback and use `await`. Or drop the callback and use `then` for the second bit of code which seems correct.

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance. I tried once using almost above same code, but had promises, it didn't work.

Comment: Funilly, the first code was working. But I did not test the error. So it was fine for "happy cases", probably not for problematic ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Promise based version of `.read` does not accept a callback, so the code in the callback is getting ignored. You also have a typo - the `status(400)` in the Promise-based version in the `.then` should be `.status(201)`. Change to:

```
jimp.read(url)
    .then((img) => {
      img.resize(120, 120)
        .quality(60)
        .write(tempURL);
      res.status(201).json({
        thumbUrl: `http://localhost:5000/${cleanedUrl}`,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(400).json({ error: `${err}` })
    })
```

As a side note, whenever you're using Node-style callbacks, identify errors by checking the first error parameter - in your original code, you're ignoring it (and the surrounding `try`/`catch` isn't accomplishing anything). For example:

```
jimp.read(url, (err, img) => {
  if (err) {
    res.status(400).json({
      error: `${err})`,
    });
    return;
  }
  img.resize(120, 120)
    .quality(60)
    .write(tempURL);
  res.status(201).json({ thumbUrl: `http://localhost:5000/${cleanedUrl}` });
});
```

Comment: Perfect! This was really helpful.